# Damaging op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, damage

What will it happen if I try to shift the 3V input signal with 1.5V or 3V. The op-amp is powered from +3V3.

[image: CircuitLab Schematic y3bd5y]

Can I damage the op-amp if  powered from GND to 3V3,  but the input signal is between +/-2V.

Comment: What op-amp are you actually using (please update the schematic)? And are you asking about the "3V" input or the "V2" input?

Comment: You write that the op-amp is powered from 3V, but the diagram shows 3.3V. Which is right?

Comment: There are really two answers to this, one that applies when the inverting input is near the supply rails, and another that applies when the non-inverting input is near the supply rails. One works sometimes, the other works never.

Answer (score 5):

Many op-amps do not tolerate the inputs going outside of their power supply range. (And some do not specify their behavior for the inputs getting within a certain voltage of the power supply range).
If you're powering the op-amp from ground and 3.3V, then the input should stay in that range.
What happens if you go outside of the range depends on the op-amp.

One possibility is that protection diodes in the op-amp become forward biased and start to conduct. These diodes are connected between the inputs and power rails such that they are reverse-biased under normal operation. If nothing limits the current to these diodes (for instance you're driving the input from a low impedance source that can drive current, expecting the input impedance to be high) then these diodes can simply fry. In so doing, they can toast adjacent silicon, since everything is close together on a chip.

If there are no protection diodes, then to understand the effect of overvoltage in either direction, we have to know the circuit schematic of the particular op-amp in some reasonable detail.  For instance, consider the JFET input stage: the inputs basically go straight to the gates of a pair of JFET transistors on the chip.  Under normal operation,  a JFET's gate-channel junction behaves like a reverse-biased diode, and so the leakage current through the gate is very small. If the gate voltage goes the wrong way (rises higher than the voltage on the drain, for an N-channel JFET) this diode can become forward biased, possibly leading to a large gate current which can destroy the JFET.

Answer (score 1):

The opamp will not be damaged but because of the TL082's somewhat quirky input stage, if the input signal goes below about 1-2V the output will saturate and invert.

There are other opamps which will continue to work much closer to their rails (see rail-to-rail types), but going beyond and still expecting proper operation is generally too much to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the data sheet ([link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbw6a/snosbw6a.pdf)) and go to page 3 where it says DC electrical characteristics, you will see that it says +/-30V for differential input voltage. So...no, it won't kill the op-amp.

Comment: I forget to take out the type of the op-amp, I meant for generally.

Comment: @KicsiMano, there isn't a general answer. It will depend which op-amp you are using.

Comment: Like what The Photon suggested, it varies from opamp to opamp. Some only let you go -100mV below rail at max. Others with built-in protection allow you to go +/-40V. Just read the electrical characteristics under absolute max ratings and determine the maximum input.

Comment: Lets say the operation voltage range is between 2.5 and 11V. I am powering the op-amp from 3V and GND but the input voltage is between +/-3V. What is happening if the gain is 1 or more? The output will be between GND and +3V?

Comment: @KicsiMano Only if the opamp is rail-to-rail (i.e. the output can go all the way to the supply voltage) and can live with an input 3V below the 'negative' supply line.